# How to insert the current date on my table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, insert

How to insert this date format on my table: `30/12/2018`?

If it's impossible, then how can i turn this date format: `2018-12-30 12:10:00` to `30/12/2018` on a `echo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the date/time in the native format (i.e. as a `datetime` or `date`).  Then, use `date_format()` to convert it to the format you want on output:

```
select date_format(datecol, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: It should be `select date_format(datecol, '%d/%m/%Y') as dateM`

Comment: echo `dateMD+%D/%M/%Y`

Answer (score 0):

You should proceed as follows :

- ensure that the field where you store the date is of type datetime or date
- use function `STR_TO_DATE` to convert strings to dates before writing to database
- use function `DATE_FORMAT` to format the datetime values to the relevant format when reading form database.

Here is a small example of `CREATE/INSERT/SELECT` :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    mydate    datetime
);

INSERT INTO mytable 
VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('30/12/2018', '%d/%m/%Y'));

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mydate, '%d/%m/%Y')
FROM mytable;
```